# Proof of the existence of a well-defined function $\bar{f}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-spaces, quotient-group, quotient-set

Given $f: X \rightarrow Y$ there exists a **well-defined** function $$\bar{f}: X /\sim  \rightarrow  Y,$$ $$[x] \mapsto f(x).$$

Such that $\bar{f}$ is injective and $f = \bar{f} \circ \pi,$ where $$\pi : X \rightarrow X /\sim, $$$$x \mapsto [x].$$

**My thoughts:**

1- I know that proving that a function is well defined means proving that its definition does not depend on the representative but I do not know how to implement that. Could anyone help me in doing so please?

2-Also, I do not know how to prove the existence of such function. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: As written it's not true.  Assume $\forall x_1, x_2 \in X ~(x_1 \sim x_2)$.  Then if $f: X \to Y$ is $1$-$1$, there is no well-defined function as required.  You need to know that $x_1 \sim x_2 \Rightarrow f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are just two sets? How is defined $\sim$?

Comment: @RobertShore Yeah I know this from the explanation before this problem. But still I am unable to solve it.

Comment: @azifmedrano Yes. $\sim$ is defined as Robert mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: I am very afraid of the notation in this problem.

Comment: @Michael How can I make it better?

Comment: We have $\sim$, $X \setminus \sim$, $[x]$, and so on, all unexplained. There also seems to be a distinction between two kinds of rightarrows, $\rightarrow$ and $\mapsto$.

Comment: @Michael $\mapsto$ is the ordinary arrow for defining a function. $\sim$ is defined in the first comment and $X/\sim = \{[x] | x\in X\}$ and $\rightarrow$ is the ordinary arrow. $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x\in X.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're trying to state should go like this:

Let $X$ and $Y$ two sets and let $f:X\to Y$.
Define for $x_1,x_2\in X$ a relation in $X$ as $x_1\sim x_2$ if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

1. Prove that this define an equivalence relation on $X$.

Now you can talk about the quotient $X/\sim \quad = \{[x]:x \in X\}$, the set of the classes of equivalence.

Define $\bar{f}(x):X/\sim \quad \to Y$ as $\bar{f}([x]) = f(x)$.
Since the definition uses an element of the class this could be ill-defined.

2. Prove that this is well defined.

Now define $\pi:X \to X/\sim$ as $\pi(x) = [x]$.

Then

3. $f = \bar{f}\circ\pi$
4. $\bar{f}$ is injective
5. $\pi$ is surjective.

I hope that stating the problem properly helps you solve it. :)

Comment: Thank you! for restating the problem. But could you please help me in the answer as this was my original question?