# Proof of the existence of a well-defined function $\bar{f}$(2)

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Here is the question I am trying to solve (it is also mentioned in the answer of this link):

[Proof of the existence of a well-defined function $\bar{f}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3815687/proof-of-the-existence-of-a-well-defined-function-barf)

Let $X$ and $Y$ two sets and let $f:X\to Y$.
Define for $x_1,x_2\in X$ a relation in $X$ as $x_1\sim x_2$ if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.

1. Prove that this defines an equivalence relation on $X$.

Now you can talk about the quotient $X/\sim \quad = \{[x]:x \in X\}$, the set of the classes of equivalence.

Define $\bar{f}(x):X/\sim \quad \to Y$ as $\bar{f}([x]) = f(x)$.
Since the definition uses an element of the class this could be ill-defined.

2. Prove that this is well defined.

Now define $\pi:X \to X/\sim$ as $\pi(x) = [x]$.

Then

3. $f = \bar{f}\circ\pi$
4. $\bar{f}$ is injective
5. $\pi$ is surjective

**For the proof of 1) and 5) I have no problem in them.**

**For the proof of 2)**

Assume that $[x_{1}] = [x_{2}]$ then $[f(x_{1})] = [f(x_{2})]$ but then what I do not know how to complete. Could anyone help me in that, please?

**For the proof of 3)**

I do not know how to do it. Could anyone help me in that, please?

**For the proof of 4)**

I know that it should be the reverse of 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to prove 2), you put square brackets around $f(x_1), f(x_2)$.  These are incorrect (in fact do not mean anything as there is no equivalence relation defined on $Y$ at this point).  It should be:

---

**For the proof of 2)**

Assume that $[x_{1}] = [x_{2}]$ then $f(x_{1}) = f(x_{2})$

---

From this it is clear that $\bar{f}([x])= f(x)$ is well defined e.g. it does not matter which representative of the class $[x]$ you select.

For part 3):
$$\bar{f}\pi(x)=\bar{f}([x])=f(x),$$
by definition of the functions $\bar{f}$ and $\pi$.

For part 4): You are right it is the reverse of 2):

If $\bar{f}([x_1])=\bar{f}([x_2])$ then $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ so $[x_1]=[x_2]$, by the definition of the equivalence relation.

Comment: in the proof of part 2) should not $f(x_{1})$ and $f(x_{2})$ be inside equivalence classes or no and why?

Comment: No.  The point is that whichever element $x_2$ you choose to represent $[x_1]$, you will always have $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ by definition of the equivalence relation.  Thus the output of $\bar f$ applied to $[x_1]$ is precisely the element $f(x_1)$, not an equivalence class.  (Technically you could define an equivalence relation on $Y$ by $y_1\sim y_2$ if and only if $y_1=y_2$, but the equivalence classes would be in bijective correspondence with $Y$, so you may as well work with $Y$ itself).